# I am getting an error trying to create table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
other_id int(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
FOREIGN KEY (other_id) REFERENCES other_table(id),
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, other_id)
);
```

and getting the following error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'database_name.table_name' (errno: 150)
```

am I doing something wrong? This works fine just running it in another environment rather than phpmyadmin sql environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085001/mysql-creating-table-with-fk-error-errno-150).

Note the correct answer. *Check column types* They need to match. May be your problem.

In general, Here is the authoritative guide to [FK in Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

> In addition to SHOW ERRORS, in the event of a foreign key error
>   involving InnoDB tables (usually Error 150 in the MySQL Server), you
>   can obtain a detailed explanation of the most recent InnoDB foreign
>   key error by checking the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.

EDIT: Incorporating comments

Table on PHPMyAdmin were defaulting to **MyISAM**. On Local they were defaulting to to **InnoDB**. **MyISAM** does not support FK. This does not fully explain the difference, as based on [MySql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html), It should just work, without creating the FK's. ( Perhaps a settings issue or Older Version Issue)

Comment: check the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS. Also they both need to be signed/unsigned.

Comment: so...I just tested this same sql code on my phpmyadmin setup through bluehost...rather than my local phpmyadmin (from wamp) and it worked fine without any errors...

Comment: That is odd. They both point to the same DB? If not It may be worth your while to find the difference, it seems likely that something is different. You can check SHOW CREATE TABLE *name*.

Comment: The database I use on my local was exported from the database that is off of bluehost...so not necessarily pointing to the same database but they should be exact clones of each other...I'll look into it...

Comment: There is a difference that I found that could be the problem...for creating tables on bluehost phpmyadmin the table type defaults to MyISAM and not InnoDB like it does on my local phpmyadmin...so when running a sql on my local it could be that the FOREIGN KEYS are not going to function properly with different table type being created...I am not sure that this is the problem but it just could be...

Comment: MyISAM does not support FK. It should just work, without createing the FK. Source:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Hmmm...That is good to know...I have been looking into the differences between MyISAM vs InnoDB...well thanks for all your help though

Comment: Your welcome, I've incorporated your comments into the answer.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I figured since the comments included the answer I'd select it as the accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Does `users` and `other_table` exist?

You can't have the foreign key references to non-existant tables.

You can add the references afterwards with `alter table`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_name`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
other_id int(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
FOREIGN KEY (other_id) REFERENCES other_table(id),
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, other_id)
);
```